# launch tornado app on port 80 on remote server

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, flask, virtualenv, tornado

I have a flask app wrapped in a **tornado** server and I was trying to run app on a remote server when I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 7, in <module>
    server.listen(80)
  File "/home/ec2-user/gatekeeper/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 126, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/home/ec2-user/gatekeeper/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 187, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

So I tried to use `sudo` and I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
ImportError: No module named tornado.wsgi
```

So I am wondering if I must install tornado as root which will in turn mean that my `virtualenv` is practically useless.

Comment: I highly recommend not to listen on port 80 (because it might cause some security problems). How about listen on another port and use a reverse proxy.

Comment: using nginx now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

How exactly are you launching the app and interacting with the virtualenv? Sudo removes most environment variables, which will effectively deactivate any "activated" virtualenv. If you are using `source $ENV/bin/activate`, you need to this after `sudo`. Or you can avoid using `activate` by running the virtualenv's python executable: `sudo $ENV/bin/python run.py`.